# Decrypting AES encrypted files in F#/.Net

Tags: .net, encryption, f#

I've tried to encrypt and decrypt files using the .NET crypto libraries. However, it doesn't seem to work as the decrypted file is always garbled. Any ideas where the problem lies, i.e. in the encryption or decryption?

See source code below.

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Security.Cryptography
open System.Text

// Encrypt
let encrypt (key : string) inFile outFile = 
    let aes = new RijndaelManaged()
    let encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
    let fsOut = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create)
    let cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length)
    fsOut.Close()

// Decrypt 2
let decrypt (key : string) inFile outFile = 
    let aes = new RijndaelManaged()
    let decryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
    let fsIn = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open)
    let cs = new CryptoStream(fsIn, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    let (buf : byte[]) = Array.zeroCreate (int fsIn.Length)
    cs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
    File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, buf)

encrypt "1234512345678976" @"D:\file.txt" @"D:\file.txt.enc"
decrypt "1234512345678976" @"D:\file.txt.enc" @"D:\file.dec.txt"
```

Comment: In your `decrypt` function, you have `let decryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor`. I suspect that that should be `let decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor`.

Comment: Closing the CryptoStreams will be your next a-ha  moment.

Comment: OMG! How could I miss that... :-)

Comment: By the way, solving the above gave threw another exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. This was resolved by adding cs.FlushFinalBlock() at the end of the encryption method and replacing "let" with "use" for the first three lines of each function.